# matlab on linux: lineplot not working

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-16.04

plot([1,2,3,4,5,6])

shows an empty plot.

When i run:

```
hold on;
plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3]);
plot([4,5,6],[4,5,6],'*');
```

It hows only the three stars from the second plot command.
An Area plot does work, too. But in every plot i create, no lines are showing.
I'm running ubuntu 16.04. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you just want to show all plots on the same graph?

`hold on;
plot([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3]);
plot([4,5,6],[4,5,6],'*');
hold off;`

Comment: your suggestion is fine, however the problem remains: stars show, but no line.

Comment: Have you tried to set color? Like `plot([1,2,3,4,5,6],'r')`

Comment: @MarvinNoll perhaps this [page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/resolving-low-level-graphics-issues.html) could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting matlab with

```
matlab -softwareopengl
```

solved it for me. (My ubuntu runs in a vmware VM, which graphics card implementation doesn't seems to work with opengl)

For more information see:
[matlab opengl](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html) and
[matlab Resolving Low-Level Graphics Issues](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/resolving-low-level-graphics-issues.html)

Comment: Consider adding the [link](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/resolving-low-level-graphics-issues.html) where you found the solution to the problem in your answer for other users.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
hold on;
plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3]);
plot([4,5,6],[4,5,6],'*-');
```

You need to add the dash (`-`) to specify that a line should also be drawn in conjunction with the stars. If you want a dashed line, then you add `'*--'`.

Comment: no, that wasn't the problem. The _first_ plot showing nothing is the problem. And it should show a line plot by default. Specifying '-' did nothing.